# Sull'uso di "fosserci" e forme verbali simili

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, verbs, history, tenses

Nel racconto *Il pugno chiuso*, di Arrigo Boito, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Nel settembre del 1867 viaggiavo in Polonia per certa missione medica che mi era stata affidata; doveva fare delle ricerche e degli studi intorno ad una fra le più spaventose malattie che rattristano l’umanità: la plica polonica. Benché questo morbo sia circoscritto nella sola Polonia i suoi strani effetti ed il suo nome sono conosciuti, anche dai profani della scienza, per ogni parte d'Europa; **fosserci** così pure palesi le sue cause ed i suoi rimedi.

Questo "fosserci" che appare nel testo ha attirato la mia attenzione. Immagino si tratti di una forma arcaica di "ci fossero" e che la frase in cui si trova esprima un desiderio irrealizzabile. È così?

In qualche periodo della storia della lingua era comune attaccare i pronomi e le particelle pronominali alla fine dei verbi coniugati all'imperfetto congiuntivo o ad altri tempi verbali  in questo modo? Ricercando "fosserci" con Google, ne trovo alcune occorrenze, ma non sembrano tante.

Comment: Sì, era considerato quasi obbligatorio posporre le particelle pronominali nella lingua scritta.

Comment: In effetti nel 
***Registro generale delle conjugazioni di tutt'i verbi italiani*** di Nicola Delia del 1835 oltre a *fosserci*  c’è anche *fossergli e fosservi.* https://books.google.it/books?id=vFxapNO8vw4C&pg=PA23&lpg=PA23&dq=fosserci&source=bl&ots=T8P7Z9w2Ah&sig=ACfU3U2QYdN3UHwg6Cy7nfyD7M12Su-KNA&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjZ3eS_usDpAhVB_CoKHdXwCgcQ6AEwAHoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=fosserci&f=false

Comment: @Hachi: Suppongo anche *fossermi*, *fosserti*, *fosserle*, ... e *fossemi*, *fosseti*, *fossele*,  etc. Ma, con la prima e seconda persona (singolare e plurale) come sarebbe? O solo si usava con la terza persona?

Comment: Bisognerebbe trovare una grammatica del tempo, mi sembra comunque un uso prettamente letterario o formale di allora.